# Dovecot removing my mails

Tags: dovecot, imap, pop3

Why is dovecot removing my mails? I have setup an SQL database according to the Dovecot information, but I get this in my logs:

```
May 14 14:23:53 alpha postfix/smtpd[16436]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-ie0-f174.google.com[209.85.223.174]: TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA (128/128 bits)
May 14 14:23:53 alpha postfix/smtpd[16436]: B2FD382E07: client=mail-ie0-f174.google.com[209.85.223.174]
May 14 14:23:53 alpha postfix/cleanup[16441]: B2FD382E07: message-id=<CAN-5czEh3pcyfw-eZT3m-rfyxrOXRaSpt-76uJ++H57jy=46wg@mail.gmail.com>
May 14 14:23:54 alpha postfix/qmgr[16274]: B2FD382E07: from=<kevin91nl@gmail.com>, size=1770, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 14 14:23:54 alpha postfix/smtpd[16436]: disconnect from mail-ie0-f174.google.com[209.85.223.174]
May 14 14:23:54 alpha dovecot: lda(kevin): msgid=<CAN-5czEh3pcyfw-eZT3m-rfyxrOXRaSpt-76uJ++H57jy=46wg@mail.gmail.com>: saved mail to INBOX
May 14 14:23:54 alpha postfix/local[16442]: B2FD382E07: to=<kevin@ovoweb.net>, relay=local, delay=1.2, delays=0.69/0.01/0/0.53, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf -m "${EXTENSION}")
May 14 14:23:54 alpha postfix/qmgr[16274]: B2FD382E07: removed
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: read the logs carefully.. dovecot says: "saved mail to INBOX", and **postfix** says "removed" (from the queue...)

Answer (score 2):

The log files indicate no problem. Postfix receives the email, then places the email in qmgr. Dovecot then takes the email from qmgr and places the email in the INBOX, which is defined in postfix's main.cf, as seen here:

```
May 14 14:23:54 alpha dovecot: lda(kevin): msgid=<...>: saved mail to INBOX
```

Postfix will then remove the email from the queue as seen here:

```
May 14 14:23:54 alpha postfix/qmgr[16274]: B2FD382E07: removed
```

This is normal behaviour. Is your mailbox_base directory set up with the correct permissions in postfix's main.cf? Have you checked your mailbox_base directory for emails stored in the INBOX?